# How to position a node in the corner of the (current) TikZ picture?

Tags: tikz-pgf, positioning

I'm drawing a flowchart as a standalone TikZ picture and want to position the legend in the lower right corner of the picture. How can I reference this position or find its coordinates?

Comment: `\node at (current bounding box.south east) [anchor=south east] {Legend};`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

From the comments, with additional information added:

TikZ/`pgf` define several special nodes in every `path`/`picture`. These are detailed in Section 102.4 of the manual. The one we're interested in here is `current bounding box`. The details from the manual:

> **Predefined node `current bounding box`**
>
> This node is of shape `rectangle`. Unlike normal nodes, its size changes constantly and always reflects the size of the bounding box of the current picture.

So, after drawing the whole picture minus the legend, you can do

```
\node at (current bounding box.south east) [anchor=south east] {Legend};
```

to place a `node` anchored at its south east corner, which will be placed at the south east corner of the current bounding box.

An example:

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[every node/.style=draw]
  \node at (0,0) {A};
  \node at (4,1) {B};
  \node at (2,-1) {C};
  \node at (current bounding box.south east) [anchor=south east] {Legend};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]